# Installing Server over Old R50e lenovo thinkpad

Tags: server, thinkpad

Tried several distribution starting on 6.10 which gave me an error:
Unknown Interrupt or fault at EIP 00000060.
Than went to 10.04:
Got stuck every time tried to download from a mirror.
Then finally went to the latest 14.10 which stuck on selecting the "install ubuntu server" on the first screen.

What the recipe would look like to get going here?
Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download Ubuntu mini.iso

[Here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

Burn it on a Cd.

Starts with mini.iso in cd.

Start the installation.

Choose the default language.

Select the keyboard settings.

Select the geographical configuration.

Wait for the system to configure the network.

Write the name of the host.

Choose the replica of Ubuntu.

If you use a proxy server, it will ask you to fill. Otherwise, leave it blank and continues.

Installation of basic packages starts. Occasionally stop to ask you some details.

After downloading the required packages start partitioning.

I suggest choosing manual and manually create partitions as needed.

Done, the system will ask you to confirm the changes made ​​on the computer, including formatting and editing the partitions.

The system will start the download and installation of packages; including the kernel, required for the system to function.

After downloading and installing, configure user accounts, writing full name, username and password.

After analyzing the reply, it will ask if you want to enable automatic updates.

Now comes the most important, the selection of programs.

**Do not select anything other than the server.**

Will proceed to download and install the files, and then download and install Grub, set the time zone, and warn you when you are ready to restart.

Restarting from the hard drive, it will start in a terminal.

In it via apt-get you can install programs to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately hangs right after the selecting "install" in the installer boot menu. Not giving up yet, this is something related to PAE which is not supported on Centrino (M). I am guessing.

Comment: Non-Pae, try antix: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/antix-linux/antiX-15-V_386-full.iso

Comment: Ok, went to expert install with command-line. Got the following message ERROR: PAE is disabled on this Pentium M. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU. \n Ok downloading ... ... ... :)